# Cannot resolve symbol assertThat

Tags: android, android-testing

I have the following dependencies in my `build.gradle` file

```
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
```

And my test class `EmailValidatorTest` has the following code

```
  @Test
public void emailValidator_simpleEmail_returnsTrue(){

   assertThat(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name@ex.com"),is(true))
}
```

But i get the error as `Cannot resolve symbol assertThat`. I get only `assert` object .I'm currently working on a sample from `Android Developers` i,e : `https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/unit/BasicSample`.

Comment: That did the trick...Thank u so much!!!

Comment: @Android Move ahead .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure you imported **[assertThat](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat(T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher))**.

```
public static <T> void assertThat(T actual,
                                  org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> matcher)
```

> import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

Then **Clean-Rebuild-Run** .

Comment: There's no difference between `testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '1.9.5'` and `testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'`, as per [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Here follows what worked to me:

At app/build.gradle:

```
testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.43'
```

At EmailValidatorTest class:

```
import com.google.common.truth.Truth;
```

and inside emailValidator_simpleEmail_returnsTrue() method:

```
Truth.assertThat(EmailValidator.isValidEmail("name@ex.com"),is(true))
```

See, you don't import 'assertThat' directily, oposite to what is said in the tutorial.

[Here an example.](https://github.com/bruno-sl15/HeyFoodApp/commit/67de56f31a4fab174b36dd94fdfbac1590e08738)